# Generic way to select top N rows from table using JDBC

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'd like to select top {n} rows from sql-server
`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM CUSTOMER;` --> n should be configurable

How can I do this using JDBC?
Should I write a prepared statement and supply ? instead of 10?
Or Should I construct the SQL string and execute it as normal statement?

I just want to know if there's a de facto choice of supplying dynamic FETCH LIMIT (a configured value usually)

Comment: Are you looking for [`Statement.setMaxRows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-)?

Comment: Would you like to build a query which you inform the number of the TOP statement?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **Pageable** with **JPA** like this refer to https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results

```
Page<Passenger> page = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "seatNumber")));
```